# How to connect in java as SYS to Oracle?

Tags: java, database, oracle, sys

I receive this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER
```

How to fix? (I need to be `SYS`).
Thanks.

Comment: Please show the code which you use to connect.

Comment: When you say "in java", do you mean "via JDBC"?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

try this :

```
import java.sql as jsql
import java.lang as lang
driver, url, user, passwd = (
"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1234:xxx1",
"sys as sysdba",
"xxx1")
 lang.Class.forName(driver)
 c = jsql.DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,passwd)
```

Comment: What is that, Groovy?

Comment: The question is asked in java.

Comment: whats the way in tomcat server.xml file?

Comment: proper jdbc url for sys as sysdba: "jdbc:oracle:thin:sys as sysdba/mysecretpassword@127.0.0.1:1521/xe", tested with xe 11.2.0.2.0

Answer (score 17):

Answers already there,

you are trying to connect as `sys` but the Server allows

either

```
sys as sysdba
```

or

```
sys as sysoper
```

just change user parameter as either one from above

```
user='sys as sysdba'
```

or

```
user='sys as sysoper'
```

Answer (score 8):

This code works

```
String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
String nameForConnect = "sys as sysdba";
String pass = "password";
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.1:1521:ORCL";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, nameForConnect, pass);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have attempted to connect to the database like this: `connect SYS/<password>` you have used a syntax that is no longer valid (After Oracle 9i).

Instead try to connect as the following:

```
connect SYS/<password> as SYSDBA or connect SYS/<password> as SYSOPER
```

Comment: The question was about connecting via Java, which I presume means JDBC. The commands you gave are for use with SQL*Plus, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use an OracleDataSource Object?

```
public class Database {    
    static OracleDataSource ods;    
    public static Connection openConnection(String URL, String user, String password,     String option) throws SQLException
    {
            Connection conn = null;
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("user", user);
            properties.put("password", password);

            ods = new OracleDataSource();
            ods.setURL(URL);

            if(option != null)
            {
                properties.put("internal_logon", option);
            }

            ods.setConnectionProperties(properties);
            conn = ods.getConnection();

            return conn;
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Connection con = null;    
con = Database.openConnection("YourJDBCConnectionURL", "YourSYSUser", "YourSYSPassword", "sysdba");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect your database with user other than "sys" as "sysdba" then you have to change the driver from "thin" to "oci" to make the successful connection.

```
try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        String DB_URL="jdbc:oracle:oci:@localhost:1521:orcl";
        OracleDataSource ds1=new OracleDataSource();
        Properties prop1 = new Properties();
        prop1.setProperty("user","ravi");
        prop1.setProperty("password","******");
        prop1.setProperty("internal_logon","sysdba");
        ds1.setConnectionProperties(prop1);
        ds1.setURL(DB_URL);
        OracleConnection conn1 = (OracleConnection)ds1.getConnection();
        Statement stmt = conn1.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from dba_users");
        while (rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        conn1.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        /*It works for me*/
        /*also oci and thin is important if you want to connect with database which is installed in your clien (Computer) add oci if you want to install to server add thin*/

        String dbURL2 = "jdbc:oracle:oci:@172.16.24.123:1521:XE";
        String username = "sys as sysdba";
        String password = "XX Change it to your system password";
        
        try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL2, username, password);
            System.out.println("Connected to Oracle data");
        
    } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Opps ! error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put sysdba with user String parameter like

```
String user="sys as sysdba"
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents as I ran into the same exception. Following did the trick for me:

```
           try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserverip:1521:XE", "sys as sysdba", "Hello123")) {   
           // this worked too - "jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserverip:1521:XE", "system"
              if (conn != null) {
                  System.out.println("Connected to the database!");
              } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
              }
 
            } catch (SQLException e) {
              System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
```