# connecting oracle using springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, oracle18c

I am using spring boot as framework in my code and oracle 18c as database.
I have written the following properties for the connection :

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@//127.0.0.1:32118/XE
spring.datasource.username =****
spring.datasource.password =****
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name==oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

However, while running the application, I am getting the following error :

```
ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException.595 - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER
```

How can I specify role as SYSDBA in my properties file? Is there any other way to provide role?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101517/how-to-connect-in-java-as-sys-to-oracle/10111464#10111464

Comment: @user7294900 Actually, I am looking for a way to specify it using properties or by creating a configuration of datasource in spring boot