# ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied when connection

Tags: oracle, go

I get the given below error, when I connect `localhost` (docker - oracle-12.2.0.1) using Go. Same connection is working fine when I connect by `table plus`. Please suggest me to resolve this issue.

[Reference](https://golangexample.com/an-example-of-using-oracle-db-with-golang/)

**Code**

```
conn, err := sql.Open("oracle", "oracle://SYS:Oradoc_db1@localhost/ORCLPDB1.localdomain")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Can't open the driver", err)
    return
}
```

**Error1**

```
ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER
```

**Code**

```
conn, err := sql.Open("oracle", "oracle://SYSDBA:Oradoc_db1@localhost/ORCLPDB1.localdomain")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Can't open the driver", err)
    return
}
```

**Error2**

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Comment: I think the error is clear and it is not related to golang, try to check with username/password, maybe Case Sensitive issue or other you need to debug that

Comment: Let me check thanks @ManjeetThakur

Comment: User `sys` cannot connect to the Oracle DB "as is", because is is granted `sysdba` role. It should use special addition to its user name: `sys as sysdba`. See [Admin guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/getting-started-with-database-administration.html#GUID-5F1E393E-97B8-43BC-BD68-3595251A6F7C) guide. You may check [similar question regarding java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101517/how-to-connect-in-java-as-sys-to-oracle).

Comment: See Oracle DB connection examples in https://github.com/godror/godror/blob/main/doc/connection.md

Answer (score 0):

The username and password must be same as was specified in a GRANT CONNECT statement.
And if you are entering the username and password together the format should be like this : `username/password`.
Also check if they are case sensitive or not.

try this format :

```
 db, err := sql.Open("oracle", "<your username>/<your password>@service_name")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()
```

OR

Also confirm golang oracle database driver

```
db, err := sql.Open("goracle", username+"/"+password+"@"+host+"/"+database)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("... DB Setup Failed") 
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
defer db.Close()
```

Comment: The current Oracle DB driver to use is "godror". see https://github.com/godror/godror